# Question about a column associated with duplicated entries in another column

Tags: r

I have 2 data sets that I would like to merge them in a specific way,

```
d1 <- read.table(text="
 a        c   
 1       100    
 2       1000   
 3       10000", header=TRUE)

d2 <- read.table(text="
 a      b          
 1      x       
 1      y       
 2      x  
 2      x    
 2      y        
 3      x", header=TRUE)
```

For the same value of "a", there are only 2 different "b" values: "x" and "y", I would like to divide the value of "c" by the number of "x", and the number of "y". That is, for each "a" value, all "x" share the the original c value, as well as "y". 
The output like follows,

```
# dataset 2
#     a      b      c    
#     1      x     100
#     1      y     100
#     2      x     500
#     2      x     500
#     2      y     1000
#     3      x     10000
```

I have tried library(dplyr), but not sure which is the best way to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: how do you devide the string "10,000" into n parts? Be scientific here. Is the 10000 or 10. You need to deal with that step first.

Comment: do you mean something like `left_join(dataset2,dataset1,by="a")`? What's the deal with "dividing the value"?

Comment: `df2 %>% group_by(a, b) %>% dplyr::mutate(part = n()) %>% merge(., df1, all = TRUE) %>% mutate(c = c/ part) %>% select(-part)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after

```
left_join(d1, d2) %>% group_by(a, b) %>% mutate(c=c/n()) %>% 
  select(a,b,c)

#       a b         c
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
# 1     1 x       100
# 2     1 y       100
# 3     2 x       500
# 4     2 x       500
# 5     2 y      1000
# 6     3 x     10000
```

Here we join then group by the values in each a/b combination and normalize by the count